# how to get multiple object array value into view just using 1 ng-repeat in angular-laravel

Tags: arrays, angularjs, laravel, object, angularjs-ng-repeat

i'm new with laravel and angular things. so i try to get data from 3 table and create 3 different variable with model in each variable and in angular controller i got data result as $scope.document_url. first this is my 3 object data :

[image: data]

and i want to know is it possible to get all 3 object into 1 in just using 1 ng-repeat? this is what i do in my angular view :

```
<tr md-row md-auto-select ng-repeat="(key, value) in document_url[0]">
```

so i want just document_url not document_url[0] to get all array value in all object in 1 ng-repeat. thanks for helping me sorry bad english. if you dont understand my explanation i will try to explain more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not use two ng-repeats one inside the other?

```
<tr md-row md-auto-select ng-repeat="outerObj in main_array">
   <span ng-repeat="innerObj in outerObj">{{outerObj.Id}} - {{innerObj.Id}}</span>
</tr>
```

Comment: the above will work you can use 3 repeats and then access all objects from the innermost repeat it will work I have done this many times stick at it

Comment: how to know the object values i get from each ng-repeat? like console.log to see array values after ng-repeat. thanks

Comment: okay it works but can't use <span> to show data without <td> and i need to add ng-repeat and span in every <td> to make it works. thanks for advice btw.